# How to convert a datetime from a specific timezone to its UTC version using the django.utils.timezone library?

Tags: django, python-datetime, django-timezone

I am looking for a function from the django.utils.library that would take a datetime from a specified timezone and return its UTC equivalent.  Does such a function exist?

Comment: do you need this functionality done using django's utils library or would you like a solution based on datetime library ?

Comment: I am also interested in the datetime library solution

Comment: also just to confirm, do you want to localize the time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a datetime object that already has timezone information to another timezone (UTC in this case) you can use [django.utils.timezone.localtime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.localtime)

```
from django.utils.timezone import localtime, utc
datetime_object_as_utc = localtime(datetime_object, timezone=utc)
```